# How to keep track of methods used in Java

Tags: java, refactoring, code-cleanup, dead-code

Is there a way to keep track of methods from all files used by a particular module (all files that are used to complete the functionality of a module) without using existing tools.

I would like to hear your thoughts on how to design a tool that would get the code coverage of a C and Java file using java.

My idea is quite tedious because I  will extract method names line by line and search for the corresponding file in the directory where it is stored. Then starting from that file, extract the methods that are called, and the process goes on until every method is checked

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without using a plugin, but, e.g., IntelliJ (and Eclipse) have the ability to flag unused code for a source file open inside the IDE.

Comment: Yes, i made my research and I couldnt find a way without using existing tools/plugins. @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: What is the problem with handling this in your IDE?

Comment: They only gave me the directories of the folders used. That's why I cant handle it by IDE only.

Comment: Making a tool doing this reliably in a week may be a challenge using the plugins API. Using existing plugins is the way to go. UCDetector is pretty good with eclipse.